# Setting interface pointer in WM_CREATE, becomes NULL in WM_COMMAND

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, com

I am learning COM, currently without following any particular architecture, I am loading my own library instead of using COM engine. I load my library in `WM_CREATE`, create interface pointer to ISum,

```
            hServerLib = LoadLibrary(TEXT("QIPropertiesServer.dll"));
            if(hServerLib == NULL)
            {
                MessageBox(hwnd, TEXT("Required Library could not be found"), TEXT("Error!!"), MB_OK);
                DestroyWindow(hwnd);
            }
            pfnCreateComponentInstance = (PFN_FUNCTION)GetProcAddress(hServerLib, "CreateComponentInstance");
            if(pfnCreateComponentInstance == NULL)
            {
                MessageBox(hwnd, TEXT("Your function is not exported from dll"), TEXT("Error!!"), MB_OK);
                DestroyWindow(hwnd);
            }
            pfnCreateComponentInstance(IID_ISum, (void**)&pISum);
            if(FAILED(hr))
            {
                MessageBox(hwnd, TEXT("isum interface is not found"), TEXT("Error!!"), MB_OK);
                DestroyWindow(hwnd);
            }
```

Then, while handling button click in `WM_COMMAND`, I try to use this pISum, it is `NULL` there.

```
switch(LOWORD(wParam))
                    {
                        case    IDENTITY:       
                                        hr = pISum->QueryInterface(IID_ISubtract, (void**)&pISubtract);
```

Comment: ohh.. in between I call DefWindowProc(), also, WndProc()  is callback, and pISum is local to WndProc. So I guess as soon as it goes out of scope, variables are nullified. Is this correct?

Comment: BTW, the correct way to destroy a window from inside its `WM_CREATE` handler is to return -1 instead of calling `DestroyWindow()`, per the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632619.aspx).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All variables shared between different states in a WindowProc need to have static storage duration, because the WindowProc is called repeatedly by the OS. Local variables will not be preserved between calls.

You likely get the variable as NULL because you are running in a debug build, or maybe just out of luck. It might as well have contained random garbage.

Comment: `NULL` is the good luck outcome. The bad luck outcome is that you get the value that was assigned last time through!!